# What does having a Facebook access token allow?

Tags: facebook, token

If you get the Facebook access token of a particular website that allows you to login with Facebook as an account on the website that belongs to some user, what can you do with it? Can you login to the actual website with that user's account? If so how? It seems a bit unclear to me.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

Hence its name, an access token permits an access to the API.

If you get an access token, you can indeed use it and `GET` / `POST` as the user. Your action field depends on the permissions that have been accepted before its creation and can't be changed. Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=education&access_token=CAAFrCZBaL1WoBAPTOEV9Tz
```

However, you couldn't log in to the website that generated the access token, because this is handled on the website server. Nothing makes it possible to input the access token, because the server can only get it as an answer from the access token request made to Facebook.